# Fedex shipping carrier weight more than 150lbs

Tags: magento-1.8, php, fedex

I am using magento Community 1.8.1 I am using fedex shipping carrier, **I want to set up fedex such like that it take individual product in cart for shipping and calculate rate instead of taking all the product in cart in one box because it does not allow more than 150 lbs in one box , I want to ship more than that.**

please consider scenario, my product weight is 15lbs and I want to ship more than 10 product at a time but fedex doesn't show any shipping method for more than 10 products , how could I do it? either I have to do setup in fedex account or I have to change my coding.

please give right Suggestion.

Comment: You should first read this
>http://www.fedex.com/us/service-guide/our-services/us/index.html?qgroup=toggle-c2&qid=FedEx_Standard_Overnight

Answer (score 2):

FedEx International Priority allow shipments up to 68kgs. With FedEx Freight you would be able to process shipments up to 999kgs. change the service if you want to ship packages with more than 68kgs.

Comment: My credentials correct, i have two store in single magento, store 1 display Fedex shipping cost, but store 2 not displaying shipping cost, how can i solve this issue?